# Why ResultSet isn't null,But I can't get data from the ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql

```
public List<Course> searchCourse(String name) {
        List<Course> list = null;
        Course course = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
        ResultSet rs = null,rs1 = null;

        String sql = "select username,course_name from view_teacourse where username=? or course_name=? ";

        try{
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, name);
            pstmt.setString(2, name);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while(next()){
                String sql1 = "select * from courseinfo where course_name=?";
                pstmt.setString(1, rs.getString("cousre_name"));
                rs1 = pstmt.executeQuery();
                while(rs1.next()){
                    course.setCourseid(rs.getInt("course_id"));
                    course.setCourseName(rs1.getString("course_name"));
                    course.setCourseScheme(rs.getString("course_scheme"));
                    course.setCourseBook(rs.getString("course_book"));
                    course.setCourseTerm(rs.getString("course_term"));
                    course.setIntroduction(rs.getString("introduction"));
                    course.setStartTime(rs.getTimestamp("start_time"));
                    course.setEndTime(rs.getTimestamp("end_time"));
                    course.setValidation(rs.getBoolean("validation"));
                    course.setCourseType(rs.getInt("coursetypeid"));
                    list.add(course);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            DBBase.releaseResultSet(rs1);
            DBBase.releaseResultSet(rs);
            DBBase.releaseStatement(pstmt);
            DBBase.releaseConnection(conn);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The value of `rs.next()` is getting false. It cannot go into the while loop. But if I write `rs.wasNull()` so I got false again. So I'm confused. I can get the right result use the same SQL in my database. When it in a java file it doesn't work! I can't find where is wrong!

Comment: What is next() method doing?

Comment: You say rs.next() is false. That means you didn't find any matches for 'name' in the database. All your other problems stem from that.

Comment: `Course course = null;`
but this is never initialized with an object..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code this way, but it's a classic (n+1) latency trap.  It'll perform worse and worse as the size of the outer result set grows.

You can also bring all the data back in one network roundtrip if you learn how to write a JOIN properly.

If you must do it this way, I would create two PreparedStatement instances: one for the outer loop and another for the inner one.

Comment: Can U tell me what is a classic(n+1) latency trap?I don't hear it before.Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

`while(next()){` needs to be `while(rs.next()){`, doesn't it?

(it does, but @duffymo's answer is the one you should probably pay attention to)

Comment: sorry...I use rs.next() in my file.This is a mistake when I copy my code!Thank U!

Answer (score 0):

This certainly looks like a typo:

```
pstmt.setString(1, rs.getString("cousre_name"));
```

You also don't seem to be assigning anything but `null` to `course`. Java's definite assignment rules are your friends; `null` is not.

Are you sure this is *exactly* the code you are running?